# What is the best way to bind multiple event handlers to a single element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

```
let typingTimer;

//Detect keyup focusin, focusout and keydown events on the search input and 
//handle them.

$searchInput.on('keyup focusin focusout keydown', (keyPressed) => {
    //Restart the search timer on each event so the server doesnt get 
    //spammed with multiple requests at a time.

    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if (event.type == 'keyup' && $searchInput.val() && keyPressed.keyCode >= 65 && keyPressed.keyCode <= 90) {
        //Execute search after certain amount of time.
        typingTimer = setTimeout(searchFunction, debounceTime);
    } else if (!$searchInput.val()) {
        //Empty the search list if user erases everything in the input.
        $searchChampList.empty();
    } else if (event.type == 'focus') {
        //Show the search list if the user clicks on the search input.
        $searchChampList.fadeIn(300);
    } else if (event.type == 'blur') {
        //Hide the search list if the user clicks out of the search input.
        $searchChampList.fadeOut(300);
    } else if (event.type == 'keydown' && $searchInput.val() && keyPressed.keyCode == 40) {
        //Navigate the search list with down arrow and enter the champs name into the input for feedback.
        $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted').next().addClass("search__champ-list-item_highlighted");
        $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted').prev().removeClass("search__champ-list-item_highlighted");
        $searchInput.val() == $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted.search__champ-name').text();
    } else if (event.type == 'keydown' && $searchInput.val() && keyPressed.keyCode == 38) {
        //Same as above but with up arrow.
        $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted').prev().addClass("search__champ-list-item_highlighted");
        $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted').next().removeClass("search__champ-list-item_highlighted");
        $searchInput.val() == $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted.search__champ-name').text();
    } else if (event.type == 'keydown' && $searchChampList.children().length >= 1 && keyPressed.keyCode == 13) {
        //Pressing enter goes to the highlighted champs page.
        window.location.href = $('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted').attr('href');
    }
});
```

It's looking a little messy and hard to read IMO, and the only expression using all 4 events is `clearTimeout(typingTimer)`. Is it a better practice in this case to just break them up into separate event methods?

```
$searchInput.event((handler){
    //code
})
```

Comment: The code can be simplified a lot

Comment: Looks fine to me. Looks like it works... there is only so much you can do for the readability. I would suggest caching `$('.search__champ-list-item_highlighted')`. Otherwise though, this is mostly opinion based as it depends on the coding style of the place where you are working.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Can you give me a suggestion to simplify the code besides assigning the selectors to a variable? Thanks again.

Comment: @Peeper That should be on CodeReview

Comment: As long as you have the oddball `else if (!$searchInput.val())` amongst the branches, I think you are stuck with this code structure.

Comment: Where is the `event` variable declared? The argument to the handler is the event, but you named it `keyPressed`, so it should be `keyPressed.type`.

Comment: Also, you might want to avoid using arrow functions as event handlers, because then you can't take advantage of jQuery setting `this` to the event target.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Thanks, I didnt know about codereview stack exchange.

Comment: @Peeper Your question was put on hold while I was typing my answer so I can't post it, so I guess here you go: https://pastebin.com/jAceBbCT

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you split it. In this case, you are putting everything in a big function with many and many ifs, which is not easy to read (it also makes the code harder to maintain). When any of the events are called you are going to execute all the verifications to then execute a single and simple piece of code.

This is a simple thing but if you still doing the same for all your code you will really start seeing the problem.

Also, if you are using jQuery, it assures that handlers are fired in the same order they were defined, so you could define the clearTimeout for all the events first and then write the specific callbacks.

Comment: Generally, we frown on providing answers to questions that don't belong here in the first place because it encourages more of the same. Those kinds of answers will get you down voted. But, you are new here and my advice would be to work on building your reputation to 40 so that you can comment on questions, which is really what this question deserves.

Comment: @ScottMarcus seems like a weird question to close. He's just asking for best practices on handling events in jQuery.

Comment: @Ben We get a lot of questions that ask for our input, but Stack Overflow is about *specific* questions about *specific* issues/problems. Questions that don't have definitive answers aren't for Stack Overflow and are the reason we have specific close reasons of "Too broad"  and "Primarily Opinion Based".